# On the fly bitmap editing in Android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, alphablending

I'm creating a scene for a game.

There's a background which is a bitmap and player objects. I want to have the player objects to be able to "eat" away at the background with a transparent color as they move around the board. Basically if an object is at a certain point a circle around that object is alpha'ed out of the bitmap. The edits of the bitmap need to persist.

What's the best way to accomplish this? I was thinking of modifying the pixels for the bitmap using Bitmap.setPixel but that would probably be very expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
I need to basically use Canvas's draw functions which are applied to a bitmap.
IE
Canvas.drawBitmap()